# Output of non-existent values when grouping in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, i have a table with the data:
**Screenshot**
[image]

This table named "**table**".

I have the SQL query:

```
select
    kind,
    count(kind)
from table
where region = 'eng'
group by kind
```

And I get the result:
[image]

Question: how do I write a query that would return *all* the values that are in the **kind** field (or any other field that can be in ***group by***)? Even if this value is 0. For the example above, the desired result is
[image]

It is mandatory to use ***group by*** in the query.

I use a postgresql 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a conditional aggregation

```
select
    kind,
    count(case region when 'eng' then kind end) cnt
from table
group by kind
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select
 t1.kind,
 coalesce(t2.total, 0) total
from 
(
 select distinct kind from table
) t1
left join 
(
 select
  kind,
  count(kind) total
 from table 
 where region = 'eng'
 group by kind
)t2
on t1.kind = t2.kind
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3d8f21ee6125021cf13f5b4cec2ae750)